# Why doesn't my XSLT key lookup work?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<errorsSortedIntoRows>
  <row y="044">
    <error x="002" y="044" errorClass="early" deviation="-2"/>
    <error x="002" y="044" errorClass="early" deviation="-5"/>
    <error x="002" y="044" errorClass="early" deviation="-3"/>
  </row>
  <row y="045">
    <error x="023" y="045" errorClass="late" deviation="20"/>
    <error x="023" y="045" errorClass="late" deviation="10"/>
    <error x="013" y="045" errorClass="wrong" deviation="33"/>
    <error x="013" y="045" errorClass="wrong" deviation="40"/>
  </row>
</errorsSortedIntoRows>
```

And I want to eliminated all duplicates with regards to x and y:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version=1.0 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="xyLookup" match="error" use="concat(@x, '|', @y)"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
      <xsl:sort select="@y"/>
      <xsl:sort select="@x"/>
      <xsl:sort select="@deviation"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="error[@errorClass = 'early']">
  <xsl:value-of select="key('xyLookup', concat(@x, '|', @y))[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="error[@errorClass = 'late']">
  <xsl:value-of select="key('xyLookup', concat(@x, '|', @y))[last()]"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- For cases that are wrong, we just toss the duplicates. -->
<xsl:template match="error[not(generate-id() = 
                               generate-id(key('xyLookup', concat(@x, '|', @y))[1]))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For whatever reason, the only output I get is the row tags, all the error tags are no longer there:

```
<errorsSortedIntoRows>
<row y="001"/>
<row y="002"/>
<row y="003"/>
.
.
.
<row y="055"/>
</errorsSortedIntoRows>
```

This even used to work, but I changed the name of some of the tags and attributes and everything just stopped working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a hunch, but try changing your `xsl:value-of`'s to `xsl:copy-of`'s.

Comment: @DanielHaley Wow, it does indeed seem to work! I could've sworn it was value-of before as well though. Oh well, all is well that ends well, I suppose. Make it an answer so that I can accept it, will you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `xsl:value-of`'s to `xsl:copy-of`'s...

```
<xsl:template match="error[@errorClass = 'early']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('xyLookup', concat(@x, '|', @y))[1]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="error[@errorClass = 'late']">
  <xsl:copy-of select="key('xyLookup', concat(@x, '|', @y))[last()]"/>
</xsl:template>
```